# Why doesn't my array or my function work?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function

Why doesn't my array (or my function) work?
I have been wondering about this for a long time now.
I have been getting no errors OR warnings from GCC, and I want to move a card from one of the handCards or playerCards, and I don't get any visible results...
minimal reproducible example (I believe it is in either function 'centerCardStack' or array 'move', edited in main()):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
char playerName;
int row, col, toStack;
int validityCheck;
int move[4];
int centerCardsOne, centerCardsTwo, centerCardsThree, centerCardsFour, centerCardsFive;
int playerCardsComOne, playerCardsComTwo, playerCardsComThree, playerCardsComFour, playerCardsComFive;
void centerCardStack(int section, int card, int toCenterStack){
    //edit the center stacks from a persons selection
    //and edit the persons handCards or playerCards
    if(playerName == 'P'){ //test who player is, later code is 'P'
        if(section==1){ //test secion. 1 is playercards, 2 is handcards
            if(card==1){ //test card. if card is one, first card...
                if(toCenterStack==1){ //test which stack
                    if(playerCardsComOne-1==centerCardsOne) //test if valid
                        centerCardsOne++;
                    else //or not
                        validityCheck=1;
                }
                if(toCenterStack==2){
                    if(playerCardsComOne-1==centerCardsTwo)
                        centerCardsTwo++;
                    else
                        validityCheck=1;
                }
                if(toCenterStack==3){
                    if(playerCardsComOne-1==centerCardsThree)
                        centerCardsThree++;
                    else
                        validityCheck=1;
                }
                if(toCenterStack==4){
                    if(playerCardsComOne-1==centerCardsFour)
                        centerCardsFour++;
                    else
                        validityCheck=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void beginCode(){
    srand(time(0));
    playerCardsComOne = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    playerCardsComTwo = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    playerCardsComThree = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    playerCardsComFour = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    playerCardsComFive = (rand() % 12) + 1;
}
//run the above
int main(){
    playerName='P';
    beginCode();
    printf("handcards: %2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d\n", playerCardsComOne, playerCardsComTwo, playerCardsComThree, playerCardsComFour, playerCardsComFive);
    printf("center---: %2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d\n", centerCardsOne, centerCardsTwo, centerCardsThree, centerCardsFour, centerCardsFive);
    printf("move> ");
    scanf("%d", move);
    row=move[0];
    col=move[1];
    toStack=move[2];
    centerCardStack(row, col, toStack);
    printf("aftermove: %2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d\n", centerCardsOne, centerCardsTwo, centerCardsThree, centerCardsFour, centerCardsFive);
}
```

I am using Linux Mint 19.3 64-bit, using GCC 7.4.0, running on a Gateway NV78 laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo @ 2.2 Ghz (Intel Centrino).
I haven't seen anything that will help me.
can anyone help me? All I got from the code is headaches...

Comment: What is it that happens when you run your code? Does the application crash?

Comment: `scanf("%d", move);` That is only going to store one `int`. It seems you expect it to do more than that: `row=move[0]; col=move[1]; toStack=move[2];`

Comment: You've obviously used another language, and not checked that things work the same way in C or C++.   `scanf("%d", move);`   where `move` is an array does not read all elements of that array.   It reads a single `int` into `move[0]` and leaves the rest of the array elements unchanged.   Yes, I know a call of `scanf()` like that in some other languages will read all elements of the array, but it doesn't work that way in either C nor C++ .

Comment: oh. so do I have to do multiple scanf calls, or is their another way?

Comment: no, the application doesn't crash.

Comment: You can do it all in one. Something like: `scanf("%d %d %d", &move[0], &move[1], &move[2])` Or better still, don't need `move` at all.  `scanf("%d %d %d", &row, &col, &toStack)`

Comment: Oh! so scanf is like printf, in the way that it can use more than one format option! thanks!

Comment: thanks, kaylum! that solved my problem!

Comment: If in doubt, please, read the doc. [scanf, fscanf, sscanf, scanf_s, fscanf_s, sscanf_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). ;-) (aka. [Read The Funny Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM))

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer!
thanks to kaylum's suggestion, I used `scanf("%d%d%d", &row, &col, &toStack);` and that fixed my problem. I was trying to `scanf("%d", move);` to read the whole scanf to separate areas in move, but that didn't work.
Now, I can edit my different int's with one function.

Thanks!